# How to convert array of string to enum?

Tags: c#

How can I convert an array of string to enum?
The following code gives a basic idea about what is expected,

```
permission.Permissions.Add(Enum.Parse(typeof(PagePermission) ,a );
```

however, it throws an error like

> can not convert object to enum.

Here, `PagePermission` is enum.

```
string pagePermission = "View,Edit";
string[] permissions = pagePermission.Split(',');
permission.Permissions = new List<PagePermission>();
for (int i = 0; i < permissions.Length; i++)
{
  string a = permissions[i];
  permission.Permissions.Add(Enum.Parse(typeof(PagePermission) ,a );
}
```

Comment: When asking a question on StackOverflow, please always copy/paste the exact message of the exception. There's a lot that can be deduced from the precise wording of the error message

Comment: Please add the declaration of PagePermission enum.

Comment: public enum PagePermission
    {
        View = 1,
        Edit = 2
    }

Comment: Exact message of exception : Can not convert from 'object' to 'PagePermission' enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enum.Parse` returns an `object`, you need to cast it to the actual enum type. In your case:

```
permission.Permissions.Add((PagePermission)Enum.Parse(typeof(PagePermission), a);
```

Otherwise you'd be adding an `object` to a list of `PagePermission`, which causes the error you had.

Comment: @GoralPatel That's the `(PagePermission)` bit I added before `Enum.Parse(typeof(PagePermission), a)`. It's used to tell "I know this object is a PagePermission, so consider it as such"

Answer (score 7):

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374362/how-to-convert-array-of-string-to-enum/40374387#40374387)

```
IEnumerable<myEnum> items = myArray.Select(a => (myEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(myEnum), a));
```